# Create WSSE tags in Header on Postman

Tags: soap, postman, request-headers, wsse

A SOAP API request requires security header (with WSSE values).  It seems SOAP UI generates it from the credentials provided however, on Postman, the security header needs to be inserted manually.

I was trying to call a SOAP API endpoint using Postman. The following message was returned:

> com.sun.xml.wss.XWSSecurityException: Message does not conform to configured policy [ AuthenticationTokenPolicy(S) TimestampPolicy(S) ]:  No Security Header found;
> nested exception is com.sun.xml.wss.XWSSecurityException: com.sun.xml.wss.XWSSecurityException: Message does not conform to configured policy [ AuthenticationTokenPolicy(S) TimestampPolicy(S) ]:  No Security Header found

I added the security header (including the username token and timestamp) many and the call was successful.

How can the security header be auto-generated every time a call is made?